# How to print a complex number using python old style %?

Tags: python

When we want to print
a string we write %s
a digit we write %d
a float we write %f

I have a complex number and I want to print it.
What must I to write after %  ?

```
myComplexNumber = 5+6j
print("My Number Is: % " % myComplexNumber)
```

Thank You

Comment: `%s` works fine. The letter code after the `%` refers to how the output should be formatted, not necessarily what data type the input is; in particular, `%s` just means "whatever the `str(...)` function returns".

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using %-formatting, you could use `%s`:

```py
myComplexNumber = 5+6j
print("My Number Is: %s " % myComplexNumber)
# My Number Is: (5+6j)
```

I would suggest switching over to f-strings, which were introduced in python 3.6:

```py
myComplexNumber = 5+6j
print(f"My Number Is: {myComplexNumber}")
# My Number Is: (5+6j)
```

Comment: these 2 things are equivalent ... they arent going to remove % formatting any time soon ... why do you think this works better as a f-string? (I agree ... sort of... but maybe this needs compatibility with <3.6?) +1 though :)

Comment: One reason to use `%` formatting is that you can store the format string `"My Number Is: %s"` as data, e.g. in a file or a database, whereas an f-string is necessarily Python code, not data. (You can do the same with format strings in the `str.format` style instead, though.)

Comment: I'd say f strings are way more readable than both % and .format strings. Even if you're using python 2 for some reason, I'd still use .format over %